# Access to "Applications menu" from Mono-GTK# application under Linux

Tags: linux, mono, gtk#

How can I obtain main "Applications menu" in Mono-GTK# application under Linux?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need information about some nodes of applications-menu (application name, command line etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Read and parse the `*.desktop` files, usually in `/usr/share/applications`. (Information about these is available from the [freedesktop.org Menu Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/).)